# SUM word COUNT in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 fields:

```
cnt  str
--  -------
60   the
58   of
4    no
30   the
2    of
1    no
```

and i want result like this

```
cnt  str
--  -------
90   the
60   of
5    no
```

How would I write a query to like  below the table?

Comment: with `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT str, 
SUM (cnt) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY str;
```

This will group the table by str, ie all the will be together and then summed and so on.
if you want to rename the sum(cnt)
use:

```
SELECT str, 
SUM (cnt) as cnt
FROM table_name
GROUP BY str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
select sum(cnt) as cnt, str from my_table group by str
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this will work indeed because it is suming the cnt grouping by str as you wanted:

```
select sum(cnt),str from tablename group by str;
```

Comment: It would help to elaborate on why this would work help the OP understand what they are doing since they appear to be new to SQL.